# What is the equivalent of Spring Application Context in Koin

Tags: spring, applicationcontext, koin

I'm new to Koin and Kotlin. I'm developing a client/server application (both sides). There are several beans. Some should be configured differently for sever and client, and some can be configured similarly in both. In fact, I have two questions:

1. In Spring terms, I want to define two different application contexts each with the necessary set of beans. I think even similar beans in server and client should be different instances when running both client and server in single JVM (for testing purposes)
2. I want to know what is the equivalent of a spring application context in Koin?

Comment: take reference https://medium.com/mindorks/using-dependency-injection-with-koin-bee0b461714a

Comment: I'm not a Koin user but seems the equivalent is 'applicationContext' or 'androidContext'. Perhaps https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/152 and https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/190  can help. Seems you can define the same bean in different contexts.